# Understanding ICC and R2 in a MLM

Tags: mixed-model, multilevel-analysis, r-squared, intraclass-correlation

I have a simple repeated measures mixed-level model with random intercept by participant. I am trying to understand the resulting $R^2$ and ICC values. I have read numerous discussions on here, but none seemed to address my puzzle directly.

I have written out what I think are correct interpretations up to the final step - where my question comes:

I have the following:

1. An outcome variable, bone mineral density.
2. Three fixed effect variables: lean mass, fat mass, and age.
3. A random intercept.
4. Grouping by participant id.

I have the following:

1. Intercept variance: 0.9775.
2. Residual variance: 0.5871.
3. Total variance: 1.5646.

Adjusted ICC (the percentage variation due to clustering): 62.5%
Therefore:
The percentage variation due to within-cluster variation: 37.5%.

Unadjusted ICC (variation due to the random effect structure of the model): 0.056.

Conditional $R^2$: 0.966
Marginal $R^2$: 0.910
Therefore, 5.6% of the variation is explained by the random effect structure (same as unadjusted ICC).

Does this mean that of the 62.5% of the variation that is due to the clustering, my model is only explaining 8.96% of it (0.056/0.625)? Therefore, if I could, I should add more variables to the random effect structure, namely random slopes. Have I interpreted this correctly?

Similarly, is this saying that in the "perfect" model, the random effect structure should be able to explain 62.5% of the variation?

I have included the model output below:

```r
Linear mixed model fit by REML. t-tests use Satterthwaite's method ['lmerModLmerTest']
Formula: BMDtotal ~ 1 + leanMass_kg + fatMass_kg + age + (1 | id)
   Data: bmf_dataw_long

REML criterion at convergence: 1481.2

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-6.9223 -0.2938  0.0514  0.3555  9.3134 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 id       (Intercept) 0.9775   0.9887  
 Residual             0.5871   0.7662  
Number of obs: 504, groups:  id, 168

Fixed effects:
             Estimate Std. Error        df t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  18.83228    1.41555 172.65282  13.304  < 2e-16 ***
leanMass_kg  -0.40176    0.01428 350.68332 -28.134  < 2e-16 ***
fatMass_kg    0.82097    0.01274 436.67920  64.430  < 2e-16 ***
age           0.11966    0.02265 160.43660   5.283  4.1e-07 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) lnMss_ ftMss_
leanMass_kg -0.381              
fatMass_kg  -0.226 -0.010       
age         -0.908  0.025  0.021
```

Comment: The conditional $R^2$ should be higher than the marginal, as it includes both fixed and random effects.

Comment: @COOLSerdash Yes, thanks for pointing that out; sorry, it was a typo. I have updated the post.